# MySql running time total depending on state for ticketing

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and having trouble finding the proper commands for what I'm trying to accomplish.

We have a ticketing system that allows us to place tickets on hold. I'm trying to produce a report that will show only the time the ticket was in a non-hold state.

I'm running the query in MySQL workbench.

Here is my query to gather the information I need to achieve my goal:

```
select ID, HD_TICKET_ID, TIMESTAMP,

case when DESCRIPTION LIKE '%opened" to "hold%' then 'hold' else 'active' end as state,

DESCRIPTION

from H

D_TICKET_CHANGE
    where HD_TICKET_ID = 7715
    order by TIMESTAMP
```

Here are my results:

```
ID  HD_TICKET_ID    TIMESTAMP   state   DESCRIPTION
25040   7715    "2014-08-06 16:39:29"   active  "Ticket Created
25042   7715    "2014-08-06 17:13:15"   active  "Changed ticket Status from ""New"" to ""Opened"".
25078   7715    "2014-08-07 10:38:28"   hold    "Changed ticket Status from ""Opened"" to ""Hold"".
25081   7715    "2014-08-07 10:54:55"   active  "Changed assest name"
25201   7715    "2014-08-11 08:24:56"   active  "Changed ticket Title. Changed ticket Status from ""Hold"" to ""Opened"".
25202   7715    "2014-08-11 08:25:08"   hold    "Changed ticket Status from ""Opened"" to ""Hold"".
25341   7715    "2014-08-13 10:56:00"   active  "Changed ticket Status from ""Hold"" to ""Opened"".
25373   7715    "2014-08-13 13:41:01"   hold    "Changed ticket Status from ""Opened"" to ""Hold"".
25551   7715    "2014-08-15 13:54:21"   active  "Added resolution text. Changed ticket Status from""Hold"" to ""Closed"".
```

At this point I'm stuck. How would I add the time from 1 through 3 because the ticket is active and that time needs to be reported, but subtract 3 through 4 because the ticket is on hold, and continue this addition or subtraction to the end of these result based on active vs hold?

Comment: What do you want to add? minutes? Days (with fractions of day)?

Comment: Minutes.   Just looking for some metrix to hand to the CIO about average ticket close time with out time on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the next time stamp value.  Then you can do what you want with aggregation.  I like to use correlated subqueries for this purpose in MySQL:

```
select ID, HD_TICKET_ID, TIMESTAMP,
       (case when DESCRIPTION LIKE '%opened" to "hold%' then 'hold'
             else 'active'
        end) as state, DESCRIPTION,
       (select tc2.timestamp
        from HD_TICKET_CHANGE tc2
        where tc2.timestamp > tc.timestamp
        order by tc2.timestamp
        limit 1
       ) as next_timestamp
from HD_TICKET_CHANGE tc
where HD_TICKET_ID = 7715
order by TIMESTAMP;
```

Then, you can add up the results as:

```
select sum((case when state = 'active' then 1 else -1 end) *
           timestampdiff(second, next_timestamp, timestamp)
          ) as TimeInSeconds
from (select ID, HD_TICKET_ID, TIMESTAMP,
             (case when DESCRIPTION LIKE '%opened" to "hold%' then 'hold'
                   else 'active'
              end) as state, DESCRIPTION,
             (select tc2.timestamp
              from HD_TICKET_CHANGE tc2
              where tc2.timestamp > tc.timestamp and tc2.HD_TICKET_ID = tc.HD_TICKET_ID
              order by tc2.timestamp
              limit 1
             ) as next_timestamp
      from HD_TICKET_CHANGE tc
      where HD_TICKET_ID = 7715
     ) t;
```

This disregards the final time stamp because there is no "next" value and your question doesn't specify what to do in that case.

Comment: That is pulling the next time stamp based on the ID.   The first ID 25040 is for this ticketID, but the next time stamp 25041 that is not listed is for another ticketID.  How do i limit the next tampstamp selected to only for the same HD_TICKET_ID?

Comment: @Jay . . . The condition `tc2.HD_TICKET_ID = tc.HD_TICKET_ID` should do exactly that.